# Generic base object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How do we create a generic base object in Typescript so that we can assign objects with any additional key values?

With following code, I get this error

```
Type 'HandlerParams' is missing the following properties from type \
'{knownKey: string, unknownKey1: string, unknownKey2: string;}': \
 unknownKey1, unknownKey2
```

```js
interface HandlerParams {
    knownKey: string;
    [key: string]: any
}
 
type Handler = (args: HandlerParams) => any
 
 
function errorHandler(handler: Handler) {
    return ({logger, ...params}: HandlerParams) => {
        return handler({logger, ...params})
    }
}

errorHandler(({knownKey, unknownKey1, unknownKey2}: {knownKey: string; unknownKey1: string; unknownKey2: string}) => {
    //...
})
```

Comment: You can use `Record<string, any>`

Comment: As I know, you have to declare HandlerParams like this ```{knownKey: string;} & {[key: string]: any;}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code using generics:

```js
interface HandlerParams {
  knownKey: string;
  logger?: any;
}

type Handler<T extends HandlerParams> = (args: T) => any;

function errorHandler<T extends HandlerParams>(handler: Handler<T>) {
  return (params: T) => {
    return handler(params);
  };
}

interface UnknownKeys extends HandlerParams {
  knownKey: string;
  unknownKey1: string;
  unknownKey2: string;
}
errorHandler(({ knownKey, unknownKey1, unknownKey2 }: UnknownKeys) => {
  //...
});
```

You can read about generics here: [Official Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that every value in object is `string`, you can do this:

```js
interface HandlerParams {
    knownKey: string;
    [key: string]: any
}

type Handler = (args: HandlerParams) => any

function errorHandler(handler: Handler) {
    return ({ logger, ...params }: HandlerParams) => {
        return handler({ logger, ...params })
    }
}

type Indexed = { [prop: string]: string }

errorHandler(({ knownKey, unknownKey1, unknownKey2 }: Indexed) => {
    //...
})
```

You can use any keys in your destructured object. They all will be infered as `string`